# Div Size Automatically size of content

Tags: css

I am trying to make a h2 header for sidebar widgets but I want the width of the div class to be whatever width the content becomes. It seems I can't just set a width because those headlines with longer content then shorter content makes it break.

How can I simply make width stretch/change depending on the length of content there is? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

As far as I know, `display: inline-block` is what you probably need. That will make it seem like it's sort of inline but still allow you to use things like margins and such.

Comment: but it makes my div 100% in width which is what i don't need

Comment: @HollerTrain: What browser are you using? Cause it works perfectly here. If I remove your `width` and `text-align`, and adds that `display:inline-block` on `h2.widgettitle`, I get the result you want.

Comment: By the way, if I were you, I would run the site through the http://validator.w3.org as well as try to slim it down quite a bit. I do not have a bad internet connection and not a slow computer, but your page took almost 1.5 minutes to load. You have for example some images that are a lot bigger than they need to be; around 200kB each. Install http://getfirebug.com if you haven't, open up its Net tab and reload your page (Ctrl+F5, probably)

Comment: ah you are right! must have been an issue with Firebug. you saved my day and taught me something (more valuable!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for my submenu I needed to add: `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 65):

If you are coming here, there is high chance [`width: min-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/width#min-content) or [`width: max-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content) can fix your problem. This can force an element to use the smallest or largest space the browser could choose…

This is the modern solution. [Here is a small tutorial for that](http://thenewcode.com/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-Min-Content).

There is also `fit-content`, which often works like `min-content`, but is more flexible. (But also has worse browser support.)

This is a quite new feature and some browsers do not support it yet, but browser support is growing. [See the current browser status here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width).

Comment: This really should be the correct answer. Its the only answer that solves the problem without creating more problems. Well done and thanks.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest is:

`width: fit-content;`

Comment: Please explain your code to make it more helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 14):

If `display: inline;` isn't working, try out `display: inline-block;`. :)

Comment: does using `display:inline` limit me from using `margin-bottom` commands? now that i'm using `display:inline` i can't add bottom margin to it! thoughts?

Comment: Using just inline does, that's why I suggested using inline-block, this removes that limit.. afaik.

Comment: I needed `display: inline-flex;`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by using: `max-width: fit-content;`

Comment: Please explain your code to make it more helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to set `display: inline;`. Note, however, that in inline display, you lose access to some layout properties, such as manual height and vertical margins, but this doesn't appear to be a problem for your page.

Comment: yes when i set to `display:inline` i can't set a bottom margin which is desperately needed. thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
width: -moz-fit-content;
              width: fit-content;
```

Comment: Please explain your code to make it more helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer